# python, how to cut a part of information in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

Appreciated if anyone can help.
I am creating a database for business purpose and crawling information from a web that is written by java script. I can scrape the information but cannot cut the data that I want. Below is the whole information. Anyone know how to output only, say -

```
"mainInformation":{"fundCode":"U44437","fundCodeDisplay":"(U44437)","fundName":"JPM ASIA PACIFIC INCOME A (MTH) (USD-CASH)"
```

The data scraped is -

```
"<html><body><p>{"detailInformation":{"feeInfoSubFee":"5.00%","feeInfoSwitchingFee":"1.00%","feeInfoManagementFee":"1.500% p.a","feeInfoRedemptionFee":"0.00%","feeInfoPerformanceFee":"-","feeInfoIncentiveFee":"-","feeInfoMaxTrailerFee":"60.00%","feeInfoMaxTrailerRemarks":"-","invObjStrategy":"To provide income and long term capital growth by investing primarily in income generating securities of countries in the Asia Pacific region (excluding Japan).\r\nAt least 67% of the Fund’s assets (excluding cash and cash equivalents) will be invested in equity securities, debt securities, convertible securities and Real Estate Investment Trusts (“REITS”). Issuers of these securities will be companies that are domiciled in, or carrying out the main part of their economic activity in, the Asia Pacific region (excluding Japan) or governments or their agencies of countries in the Asia Pacific region (excluding Japan).\r\nThe Fund may invest a significant proportion of its assets in below investment grade and unrated debt securities. There are no credit quality or maturity restrictions with respect to the debt securities in which the Fund may invest. The Fund invests in financial derivative instruments in a limited extent for investment purpose.","portfolioDate":"31-07-2018","assetAllocationList":[{"assetAllocationName":"Stock","assetAllocationValue":"60.33"},{"assetAllocationName":"Bond","assetAllocationValue":"34.50"},{"assetAllocationName":"Cash","assetAllocationValue":"4.66"},{"assetAllocationName":"Other","assetAllocationValue":"0.51"}],"geoAllocationChart":"/HaseChartCenter/BasePieChart.aspx?p_ImageType=PortfolioAllocationPie&amp;p_Data=1.28259,3.29955,14.14580,40.01720,41.25486&amp;p_Legend=United States,United Kingdom,Australasia,Asia - Developed,Asia - Emerging&amp;p_Lang=0L00000122","sectorAllocationChart":"/HaseChartCenter/BasePieChart.aspx?p_ImageType=PortfolioAllocationPie&amp;p_Data=0.59690,0.94111,23.09932,9.04259,1.35411,4.83165,2.15222,2.94322,6.94703,8.42347&amp;p_Legend=Basic Materials,Consumer Cyclical,Financial Services,Real Estate,Consumer Defensive,Utilities,Communication Services,Energy,Industrials,Technology&amp;p_Lang=0L00000122","bondSectorBreakdownPieChart":"/HaseChartCenter/BasePieChart.aspx?p_ImageType=PortfolioAllocationPie&amp;p_Data=4.23195,30.86812,4.56831&amp;p_Legend=Government,Corporate,Cash and Equivalents&amp;p_Lang=0L00000122","fundGrowthChart":"/HaseChartCenter/MSChart.aspx?p_ImageType=FundGrowthLine&amp;fundCode=U44437","historicalPriceChart":"/HaseChartCenter/MSChart.aspx?p_ImageType=HistoricalPriceLine&amp;fundCode=U44437","totalNumOfStockHldg":"71","totalNumOfBondHldg":"258","topHoldingDate":"-","topHoldingList":[{"holdingName":"Taiwan Semiconductor Manufacturing Co Ltd","netAssetPercentage":"2.82"},{"holdingName":"JPM US Dollar Liquidity X (dist.)","netAssetPercentage":"3.66"},{"holdingName":"Korea Electric Power Corp","netAssetPercentage":"2.64"},{"holdingName":"China Life Insurance Co Ltd H Shares","netAssetPercentage":"2.23"},{"holdingName":"Samsung Electronics Co Ltd","netAssetPercentage":"1.99"},{"holdingName":"HSBC Holdings PLC","netAssetPercentage":"1.99"},{"holdingName":"United Overseas Bank Ltd","netAssetPercentage":"1.90"},{"holdingName":"BOC Hong Kong Holdings Ltd","netAssetPercentage":"1.86"},{"holdingName":"PetroChina Co Ltd H","netAssetPercentage":"1.81"},{"holdingName":"DBS Group Holdings Ltd","netAssetPercentage":"1.70"}],"perHistoryDate":"31-07-2018","returnCumPerList":[{"cumPerformanceReturnYTD":"-3.66","cumPerformanceReturn1Week":"-0.95","cumPerformanceReturn1Month":"0.86","cumPerformanceReturn3Month":"-3.14","cumPerformanceReturn6Month":"-4.27","calPerformanceReturn1Y":"","calPerformanceReturn2Y":"","calPerformanceReturn3Y":"","calPerformanceReturn4Y":"","calPerformanceReturn5Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn1Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn3Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn5Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn10Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn15Y":""}],"returnCumAveList":[{"cumPerformanceReturnYTD":"-6.13","cumPerformanceReturn1Week":"-1.89","cumPerformanceReturn1Month":"-1.38","cumPerformanceReturn3Month":"-5.31","cumPerformanceReturn6Month":"-7.19","calPerformanceReturn1Y":"","calPerformanceReturn2Y":"","calPerformanceReturn3Y":"","calPerformanceReturn4Y":"","calPerformanceReturn5Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn1Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn3Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn5Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn10Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn15Y":""}],"returnPastYearPerList":[{"cumPerformanceReturnYTD":"","cumPerformanceReturn1Week":"","cumPerformanceReturn1Month":"","cumPerformanceReturn3Month":"","cumPerformanceReturn6Month":"","calPerformanceReturn1Y":"","calPerformanceReturn2Y":"","calPerformanceReturn3Y":"","calPerformanceReturn4Y":"","calPerformanceReturn5Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn1Y":"-0.45","pastPerformanceReturn3Y":"3.98","pastPerformanceReturn5Y":"4.46","pastPerformanceReturn10Y":"-","pastPerformanceReturn15Y":"-"}],"returnPastYearAvgList":[{"cumPerformanceReturnYTD":"","cumPerformanceReturn1Week":"","cumPerformanceReturn1Month":"","cumPerformanceReturn3Month":"","cumPerformanceReturn6Month":"","calPerformanceReturn1Y":"","calPerformanceReturn2Y":"","calPerformanceReturn3Y":"","calPerformanceReturn4Y":"","calPerformanceReturn5Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn1Y":"-1.24","pastPerformanceReturn3Y":"3.85","pastPerformanceReturn5Y":"3.09","pastPerformanceReturn10Y":"3.47","pastPerformanceReturn15Y":"6.21"}],"returnYearPerList":[{"cumPerformanceReturnYTD":"","cumPerformanceReturn1Week":"","cumPerformanceReturn1Month":"","cumPerformanceReturn3Month":"","cumPerformanceReturn6Month":"","calPerformanceReturn1Y":"14.19","calPerformanceReturn2Y":"6.16","calPerformanceReturn3Y":"-3.05","calPerformanceReturn4Y":"7.11","calPerformanceReturn5Y":"3.56","pastPerformanceReturn1Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn3Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn5Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn10Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn15Y":""}],"returnYearAveList":[{"cumPerformanceReturnYTD":"","cumPerformanceReturn1Week":"","cumPerformanceReturn1Month":"","cumPerformanceReturn3Month":"","cumPerformanceReturn6Month":"","calPerformanceReturn1Y":"21.66","calPerformanceReturn2Y":"1.87","calPerformanceReturn3Y":"-4.60","calPerformanceReturn4Y":"3.16","calPerformanceReturn5Y":"2.93","pastPerformanceReturn1Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn3Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn5Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn10Y":"","pastPerformanceReturn15Y":""}],"returnPerValue":null,"fundLaunchDate":"25-05-2012","fundInvMarketSector":"Asia Allocation","fundType":"Balanced","hsFundType":"","fundDealingFreqeuncy":"One Dealing Session per Dealing Day/HKT 16:00","fundDealingCutoffTime":"","fundHouse":"J.P. Morgan Asset Management","fundMorningstarRatingDate":"31-7-2018","fundOverallRating":"4","threeYRating":"3","fiveYRating":"4","tenYRating":"","equValPE":"11.39","equValPC":"4.16","equValPB":"1.07","fundVolDate":"31-7-2018","fundVolOneYearSR":"-0.07","fundVolOneYearSD":"7.58","fundVolOneYearMR":"-0.45%","fundVolThreeYearSR":"0.41","fundVolThreeYearSD":"8.36","fundVolThreeYearMR":"3.98%","fundManager":[{"fundManager":"Jeffrey  Roskell","fundManagerStartDate":"01-02-2010","fundBiography":"Jeffrey Roskell, managing director, is a regional specialist for Asia Pacific inc-Japan equities with the Emerging Markets and Asia Pacific (EMAP) Equities Team based in Hong Kong. He joined the Firm in 1997 as an investment manager with the Global Equities Team (previously known as the Global Portfolios Group) in Hong Kong and then transferred to manage Asia specific portfolios in 2000. He joined the industry in 1992 as a graduate trainee with Prudential Portfolio Managers Limited in London and subsequently specialized in managing portfolios invested in Continental European equities. Jeffrey obtained an M.A. in Economics from Cambridge University and an Investment Management Certificate from the London Business School."},{"fundManager":"Julie  Ho","fundManagerStartDate":"01-01-2014","fundBiography":"Julie Ho, executive director, is a regional specialist for Asia Pacific ex-Japan equities with the Emerging Markets and Asia Pacific (EMAP) Equities Team based in Hong Kong. Julie joined the Firm in 2005 and was transferred to the team in 2013 from the U.S. Equity Group where she was a research analyst covering the U.S. and Canadian REIT sectors. Prior to that, she worked as a research assistant on the REITs sector and as an investment assistant in the U.S. Active Equity Group. Julie graduated Phi Beta Kappa from Brown University with a B.S. in Biology and a B.A. in Economics. She is also a CFA Charterholder."},{"fundManager":"Shaw Yann Ho","fundManagerStartDate":"01-01-2014","fundBiography":"-"},{"fundManager":"Selina  Yu","fundManagerStartDate":"26-02-2018","fundBiography":"-"},{"fundManager":"Ruben  Lienhard","fundManagerStartDate":"01-06-2018","fundBiography":"-"}],"performanceDataShown":true,"performanceStartYear":"2017","withPromotion":"Y","fundGroupId":"Balanced","hasMangFee":"","isIpower":"Y"},"dividendInformation":{"divInfoDate":"","divInfoCurrency":"USD","divInfoFrequency":"Monthly","divInfoYield":"4.55%","divInfoLastDividend":"0.437","divInfoLastDate":"08-08-2018"},"mainInformation":{"fundCode":"U44437","fundCodeDisplay":"(U44437)","fundName":"JPM ASIA PACIFIC INCOME A (MTH) (USD-CASH)","fundClass":"A","fundCurrency":"USD","nav":"111.24","dailyChangeAmount":"","dailyChangePercentage":"0.21%","lastDate":"17-08-2018","fundSize":"2,758,268,955.00","fundSizeCurrency":"USD","riskLevel":"3","investmentTenor":"≥ 1 Year(s) 0 Month(s)","dividendPolicy":"IC","objType":"2","mSOverallRating":"4","enbaleSubscibe":"Y","invType":"LPS","isPIFund":"N","isDerivative":"","isRQFII":"N","isHighYieldBond":"N","isFDIS":"N","isNewFDIS":"N","isMRF":"N","docARFilePath":"/ODSRevamp/0C00006C50/ODAR/0C00006C50ODAR408527E_20170630.PDF","docIRFilePath":"/ODSRevamp/0C00006C50/ODIR/0C00006C50ODIR434125E_20171231.PDF","docEMFilePath":"/ODSRevamp/0C00006C50/ODEM/0C00006C50ODEM471139E_20180801.PDF","docMMFilePath":"/ODSRevamp/0C00006C50/ODMM/0C00006C50ODMM473339B_20180801.PDF","docFSFilePath":"/ODSRevamp/0C00006C50/ODFS/0C00006C50ODFS469591E_20180630.PDF","otherFundList":[{"otherFundCode":"U85126","otherFundName":"JPM ASIA PACIFIC INCOME A (DIST) (USD)","otherFundCurrency":"USD","otherFundClass":"A","otherFundInvType":"LPS"},{"otherFundCode":"U44438","otherFundName":"JPM ASIA PACIFIC INCOME A (MTH) (HKD-CASH)","otherFundCurrency":"HKD","otherFundClass":"A","otherFundInvType":"LPS"},{"otherFundCode":"U44559","otherFundName":"JPM ASIA PACIFIC INCOME A (IRC) (AUD HEDGED) (MTH-CASH)","otherFundCurrency":"AUD","otherFundClass":"A","otherFundInvType":"LPS"},{"otherFundCode":"U44561","otherFundName":"JPM ASIA PACIFIC INCOME A (IRC) (CAD HEDGED) (MTH-CASH)","otherFundCurrency":"CAD","otherFundClass":"A","otherFundInvType":"LPS"},{"otherFundCode":"U44557","otherFundName":"JPM ASIA PACIFIC INCOME A (IRC) (EUR HEDGED) (MTH-CASH)","otherFundCurrency":"EUR","otherFundClass":"A","otherFundInvType":"LPS"},{"otherFundCode":"U44558","otherFundName":"JPM ASIA PACIFIC INCOME A (IRC) (GBP HEDGED) (MTH-CASH)","otherFundCurrency":"GBP","otherFundClass":"A","otherFundInvType":"LPS"},{"otherFundCode":"U44560","otherFundName":"JPM ASIA PACIFIC INCOME A (IRC) (NZD HEDGED) (MTH-CASH)","otherFundCurrency":"NZD","otherFundClass":"A","otherFundInvType":"LPS"}],"fundSizeDate":"31-07-2018","categoryId":"EUCA000559","retLastDate":"17-08-2018"},"majorInformation":{"sectorName":"Equity/ Bond Balanced","dealingRestriction":"Canadian Resident or US Citizen/Resident"},"uintPriceInformation":{"unitPriceDate":"17-08-2018","unitPriceNav":"111.24","unitPriceBid":"","unitPriceOffer":"","unitPriceChangePercent":"0.21%","unitPriceCurrency":"USD","unitPriceWeeks52High":"110.61-124.32","unitPriceHisChart":""}}</p></body></html>"
```

Comment: Here is the source: import sys
import re
import urllib2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulStoneSoup

request = urllib2.Request('https://rbwm-api.hsbc.com.hk/pws-hk-hase-fsm-papi-prod-proxy/v1/Funds/U44437?targetCurrency=&isPIFund=N')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print soup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that using [`json`](https://kite.com/python/docs/json) and [`urllib`](https://kite.com/python/docs/urllib2) modules

```
import json
import urllib.request


request = urllib.request.Request('https://rbwm-api.hsbc.com.hk/pws-hk-hase-fsm-papi-prod-proxy/v1/Funds/U44437?targetCurrency=&isPIFund=N%27')
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = json.loads(resp.read())
mi=data['mainInformation']
print(mi['fundCode'], mi['fundName'])
```

Comment: I am able to load the whole piece of info showing below "{u'mainInformation': {u'invType': u'LPS', u'mSOverallRating':.. ...u'Canadian Resident or US Citizen/Resident'}}. May I know how to print out fund name and fund code only. Thanks for your help.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-9c6b07da2d3d> in <module>()
      6 response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
      7 data = response.read()
----> 8 mi=data['mainInformation']
      9 print(mi['fundCode'], mi['fundName'])

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Fixed, try again

Answer (score 0):

I think the matter is translating the json string to python dictionary, you can using json model.

below is reference code, json.loads is the key method:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6  
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import json

# data.txt: full json text
f = open("./data.txt", 'r')
full_txt = f.read()
f.close()

# decode json text to python dictionary
full_txt = json.loads(full_txt, encoding='utf-8', strict=False)
# do some thing just like operate python dictionary
for k,v in full_txt.items():
    print(k,v)
```